# How to get alerted for new (unique) errors

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

A useful feature of application monitoring services is sending alerts (e.g. emails) each time a new, unique error/problem/exception occurs (i.e., not for each occurrence). Either only the very first time, or at most once per X time (a day or week or such). This is, for example, possible with Visual Studio App Center. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find any such feature in Application Insights.

For clarification, a "new, unique error/problem/exception" can be thought of as a specific log statement in the code. I'm using Serilog, so all logged traces/exceptions have a `MessageTemplate` property which may help. But ideally the "problem ID" would be based on the code location, too (since multiple log statements may use the same message template).

The best lead I have found is the ability to send alerts based on a custom analytics query, but I'm not sure if it's possible to write a query that can give a behaviour similar to (if not exactly like) to what I describe above.

Is something similar to the behaviour I describe above possible to achieve with Application Insights? If it's possible through a custom query, how might such a query look?

Answer (score 1):

Just through UI of azure portal, it's hard or impossible to achieve your first requirement: alert only the very first time. But you can try to use [app insights rest api](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/quickstart) to fetch the data, then use code to implement your logic.

There is a similar solution(not exactly like you describe) for alert once per X time. The steps are as below:

1.Nav to azure portal -> you application insights -> Alerts -> new alert rule -> in the Condition, click Add button -> then select "Custom Log Search"

2.In the "search query" textbox, write your query like below:

```
exceptions
| where xxxx
```

Note that in the `where` clause, use some properties to identify the unique error.

3.Then in the "Alert logic", use the following settings:
 Based on: Number of results, Operator: Greater than, Threshold value: 0

4.In the "Evaluated based on", set proper value for Period(max value is 2880 minutes) / Frequency(max value is 1440 minutes).

So if you want to trigger alert 1 time per day, you can set Period to 1440 minutes, set Frequency to 1440 minutes. But you also need to note that, if in the next day, there is no such specified error, it will not trigger in the next day.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is exactly the `where` clause. I updated the question with clarifications. Thing is, I don't want to be notified of a particular error I hard-code, but _all_ traces/exceptions where the level is Error or higher - but only one (daily) notification "per error". As a possible workaround, errors may be identified using a `MessageTemplate` property (but ideally the code location of errors should also be part of the ID). Is there a way to accomplish that using a `where` clause and your suggested solution?

Comment: As per my experience, I don't think it's possible to to trigger alert as "per error" in one query. You can keep this post open and see if others can have a good idea.

Comment: @cmeeren, Hello, I just want to check if you have figured out some ideas about this?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.